# A smooth function being also a vector-valued distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

This question is related to my previous one: "[Distributions valued in Fréchet spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359254/463616)".

Consider a function $u = u(t,x)$ such that

1. $u \in C^{\infty}([0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n )$
2. $u \in D'(0,T; S(\mathbb{R}^n))$

where $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of [rapidly decreasing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

> Q1) Can I conclude that $u \in C^{\infty}(0,T; S(\mathbb{R}^n))$ ?

It seems quite reasonable but I couldn't find a neat argument.

#### Further thoughts (added later)

As a first step I would like to answer the following:

> Q2) Given 1. and 2., is it possible to conclude that $u(t) \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $t \in [0,T]$?

Note that Q2) means:

$$\forall \varphi \in D(0,T) \quad \int_0^T u(t,x) \varphi(t) d t \in S(\mathbb{R}^n) \implies u(t,x) \in S(\mathbb{R}^n) \quad\forall t \in [0,T] $$

This can be informally phrased as:

> Q2') When true in the average is true pointwise?

Comment: I suppose some careful application of the Foubini theorem would do the trick here

Comment: What means $u \in D'(0,T; S(\mathbb{R}^n))$ exactly ? That $f(x) = \int_0^T u(x,t) g(t)dt$ is a Schwartz function for every $g \in C^\infty$ ?

Comment: @reuns A continuous linear map $T$, such that for any $\phi \in D(a,b)$ we have $\langle T, \phi \rangle \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  (See my other question for details.)

Comment: You need to state exactly what it means. In particular you want to look at $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_0^T u(x,t) \partial_t^k n e^{-\pi n^2 (t-t_0^2)} dt = \partial_t^k u(x,t_0)$ and show it is Schwartz (in  $x$)

Comment: I apologize @reuns, I'm missing your point. What I'm worried in the question are the decay property in $x$.

Comment: If you don't state what means $u \in D'(0,T; S(\mathbb{R}^n))$ exactly sure you will miss the point. Continuous linear functional doesn't mean anything without a topology. In which case continuity becomes a bound in term of some (semi)-norms. Also take $n=1$, the general case being similar.

Comment: The topology on $C_c^\infty$ is defined by $\phi_n \to \phi$ if there is a compact $K$ containing the support of all $\phi_n$, and $\| \partial^\alpha \phi_n \|_\infty \to 0$ for all multiindices $\alpha$.

The topology on $S$ is defined by the norms
$\|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}=\sup_{x\in\mathbf{R}^n} \left |x^\alpha D^\beta f(x) \right |$.

An $S$-valued distribution $u$ should be a continuous linear functional $C_c^\infty \to S$, i.e. if $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $C_c^\infty$ then $\langle u, \phi_n \rangle \to \langle u, \phi \rangle$ in $S$.

Comment: @F.M.R. Could you explain how 1. and 2. imply the left-hand side of the implication in your post?

Comment: @Pedro 2. means $\langle u,\varphi \rangle \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $\varphi \in D$ , while from 1.) and the usual identification of locally integrable functions and corresponding distributions, I would obtain the needed implication.

Comment: @F.M.R. It seems that the said identification makes sense only if $u$ is a vector-valued function from $[0,T]$ to $S(R^n)$. For this, you should to know that $u(t)\in S(R^n)$ in the first place, but this is what you want to prove in your Q2. Even if you know that, how would you define the integrability of such a function? The usual definition (Bochner) cannot be used because the space is not Banach.

Comment: @F.M.R. Note that the "scalar integrability" of $t\mapsto u(t,x)$ (for fixed $x$) gives a scalar distribution in $D'(0,T)$, not in $D'(0,T;S(R^n))$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pedro You're right about the ambiguity. Still $t \mapsto u(t,x)$ surely gives a distribution in $D'(0,T;C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ so maybe the question is: When we can also say it is in $D'(0,T;S(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

Comment: @Pedro About you question on the integrability, the reference I had in mind were section 1.2 of "Hamilton - The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser"  and chapter 3 of "Rudin - Functional Analysis"